# How detect when user choose NEW or OPEN mail in Outlook VSTO

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm programming a VSTO in Outlook 2016 and I would like to enable/disable buttons in a Ribbon, based on the user's action of START A NEW MESSAGE or just OPEN/READ a message.

My problem is HOW detect when the user pressed NEW MAIL or just open a sent/received one message.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) actually deals with this exact scenario:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }
```

Specifically, you attach to `this.Appliaction.Inspectors`.  The tutorial takes the opportunity to modify the `Subject` and `Body` properties of the new `MailItem`:

```
void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                {
                    mailItem.Subject = "This text was added by using code";
                    mailItem.Body = "This text was added by using code";
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason, but in this case I go to the NewInspector either in NEW MESSAGE event as the READ message event. I would like to separate these events in different routines.

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but, in case it helps anyone out there, the key (as illustrated in Jason's answer) seems to be in the mail item's `EntryID` property. If it is null, the inspector opened with a new email. If it is not null (usually a GUID-type string), the inspector was opened with an existing email. My problem is determining whether the new email is a blank email or the beginning of a reply to an existing email. but I guess that is a separate question.

Comment: @NoahBridge, the simplest way to see if is a new message is check its body content to see if it's blank (New Message) or not. Outlook is really a piece of shit, a bunch of many undocumented routines, flags, controls, etc...

Comment: Thanks, @DavidBS, for the reply! Unfortunately, in my case, new emails may start with a predefined signature, so I can't rely on the body. After posting my comment, I found 2 `MailItem` properties, `ConversationID` and `ConversationIndex`, and it seems as if the email is a reply when either of these is non-null (or non-blank). I may end up posting a new StackOverflow question to see if anyone out there can verify this. I do agree that Outlook is very incomplete in terms of its support for add-ins. Both the object model and the documentation makes development for Outlook somewhat frustrating.

Comment: @NoahBridge Did you end up finding something for this?

Comment: No, @QurakNerd, unfortunately not. I had to shift to a different task, so I have not followed up on this topic since then. I will try to post an update here if I find something new in future.